# Parsing not labeled HTML with "HTML Agility Pack" in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Using HTML Agility Pack, I want to parse a not tagged text in a HTML document.
The next HTML is an example of the HTML structure that I will treat and the text below the last div is an example of the text that I want to extract.
(The one that begins with "I am selling..." and ends in "...services or offers")

```html
<div class="mapbox">
    <div id="map" class="viewposting" data-latitude="32.965732" data-longitude="-96.882528" data-accuracy="22"></div>
    
    <p class="mapaddress">
        <small>
        (<a target="_blank" href="https://maps.google.com/maps/preview/@32.965732,-96.882528,16z">google map</a>)
        </small>
    </p>
</div>
    <p class="attrgroup">

            <span><b>2012 jeep grand cherokee laredo</b></span>
            <br>
    </p>
    <p class="attrgroup">
            <span>VIN: <b>ask me</b></span>
            <br>
            <span>condition: <b>excellent</b></span>
            <br>
            <span>cylinders: <b>6 cylinders</b></span>
            <br>
            <span>drive: <b>rwd</b></span>
            <br>
            <span>fuel: <b>gas</b></span>
            <br>
            <span>odometer: <b>98000</b></span>
            <br>
            <span>title status: <b>clean</b></span>
            <br>

            <span>transmission: <b>automatic</b></span>
            <br>

    </p>
    
        <div class="print-information print-qrcode-container">
            <p class="print-qrcode-label">QR Code Link to This Post</p>
            <div class="print-qrcode" data-location="east"></div>
        </div>
I am selling my 2012 Jeep Grand Cherokee. The Jeep runs and drives great. Zero issues. Always been well maintained and serviced on time. Very dependable car has never left me stranded. Very healthy. Everything works like it should. This Grand Cherokee would make a great family car or First car.<br>
<br>
*3.6 V6 <br>
*Automatic Transmission <br>
*98,000 Original Miles<br>
*Leather and Heated Seats<br>
*Navigation<br>
*Back Up Camera <br>
*Good Tires<br>
*Cold A/C Hot Heater <br>
*Clean Texas Title<br>
*Clean Carfax<br>
Much More!!<br>
<br>
Call or Text me for anymore information. <br>
 <a href="/fb/dal/cto/6620220745" class="showcontact" title="click to show contact info" rel="nofollow">show contact info</a>
    
            <li>do NOT contact me with unsolicited services or offers</li>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this? How to extract that text using HTML Agility Pack in .NET?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Well, the thing is that before having the problem of having to extract that text, I had to extract data like fuel, odometer, drive, etc. But it was "easy" because I could move between the labels, but the problem now is that the text that I want to extract is not framed in any label, so I do not have an idea of how I could do it.

Comment: What exactly is the 'malformed' part? It doesn't exactly jump off the page. Are there any errors?

Comment: Thant's right @HenkHolterman. I already re-edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you load the document, use xpath for selecting the text following a specific node.

```
const string xpath = "//div[@class='print-information print-qrcode-container']/following-sibling::text()[1]";
string text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath).InnerText;
```

returns:

> I am selling my 2012 Jeep Grand Cherokee. The Jeep runs and drives
>   great. Zero issues. Always been well maintained and serviced on time.
>   Very dependable car has never left me stranded. Very healthy.
>   Everything works like it should. This Grand Cherokee would make a
>   great family car or First car.

and visca catalunya!

Comment: Thanks @derloopkat !! I'll test it right now !!
visca catalunya! ;)

Comment: I tested it, and it worked perfectly. I just did some minors changes because I wanted each line, not just the first one. Thanks.